# How can I make my web application look correct in IE 8 and 9?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, compatibility

I find that my application does not look as good in IE as in Chrome and Firefox. Perhaps it shows everything in wrong way. Well, I want to solve the issue I have.

So I try my hand with IE developer tool but I find nothing to customize styles and CSS. So how do others do these things for IE?

I mean, I don't care much how it works in 6, but how can I make it look like it does in Firefox and Chrome in IE 8 or 9?

Well, what trick do you use when you need to do something in IE? Well, I know nothing in web design but I want to refactor the existing code so that it works.

So, the thing is, how can I make them compatible with IE 8 or 9? Are their any tools that exist to make them work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most important things you can do to ensure site looks *close enough* is to write standards compliant code for the doctype you have chosen, and validate that code throught [w3's validator tool](http://validator.w3.org)

After that, check out [adobe's browser labs](https://browserlab.adobe.com/) tool. You can view your site in any browser and make minor tweaks that you need.

Comment: nice thing but they not allow the developer to change something and views again.well thank @michael

Answer (score 2):

I get the best results by making my pages work in Chrome/Firefox (they tend to be similar) first, and then making adjustments to support Internet Explorer.

Sites like [Position Is Everything](http://www.positioniseverything.net/explorer.html) are good for documenting shortcomings in IE's CSS support.

I make my .css files targeted at Chrome/Firefox, and include an additional stylesheet for each IE version using [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

For example:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]> 
  <link href="/css/iefix7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" /> 
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), like @GavinH suggests, is a good way to serve IE different CSS than you serve to better-behaving browsers.

As for development, if you want better control over viewing source and fiddling with the styles and so on, try a stable version of [Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite). You may use Firebug when you develop in Firefox, so it will be more like that than the IE Developer Toolbar.